# 64 bits alternatives to linq to excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, iis-7, linq-to-excel

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application in which I want to import excel files.

I managed to do this using the `linq-to-excel` library. But when I deployed the application on IIS I got an error which turned out to be caused by IIS being running on 64bits system.

This can be solved by enabling the `32-bits applications` option for the pool in IIS.

Will this affect the performance of the application? If yes, is there another alternative to `linq-to-excel` that works on 64-bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/wiki/UsingLinqToExcel

> **x64 Support**
>
> If you want LinqToExcel to run in a 64 bit application,
>   make sure to use the 64 bit version of the library.
>
> [You will also need to make sure to have the 64 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&srcfamilyid=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&srcdisplaylang=en&u=http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D-4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe) of the
>   Access Database Engine installed on the computer.
>
> And make sure you manually set the DatabaseEngine property to
>   DatabaseEngine.Ace

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
excel.DatabaseEngine = DatabaseEngine.Ace;
```